# Salesforce For Outlook - Add Email button fails to load

Tags: email, button, salesforce-for-outlook

Salesforce For Outlook Add Emails button fails to load and "Salesforce for Outlook Add to Salesforce Toolbar" add-in is not added to Outlook under Options | Add-Ins

Please advise some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer which I was able to find and which helped me solve the issue is described here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214833&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Links can change, would be better to post some details in your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

This Knowledge article might help you

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004342&type=1

Comment: I've already tried that. SFO Add Emails button fails to load and Salesforce for Outlook Add to Salesforce Toolbar" add-in is not added to Outlook under Options